# How to establish connection between db and java code in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am making a web application in bluemix and for that, I chose java db web starter as boiler plate. I made html files in eclipse and I want db connectivity. I made a table in database (viz userInformation), but I am not getting that where and what code should be written to establish connection. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're deploying a Liberty application, and using the SQLDB service, the connection information and the db driver jar should be automatically configured in the server.xml and a datasource is created for you. You can access it using JNDI. Take a look at this example:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/02/07/java-db2-10-minutes/

Your other option is to parse the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable and read the connection information out of it. Example: https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/get-started-java

The Bluemix documentation has a lot information on how to make the connection for each services.

Also, you will need to have some server side java code like a Servlet to make this db connection. You can not connect directly from your client side html code.

https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/java-db